# How to work with dfspace command?

Tags: path

I am trying to execute dfspace command but I am getting the error

```
root@Kali:~# /dfspace
-bash: /dfspace: No such file or directory
```

Comment: root@Kali:~# dfspace

-bash: dfspace: command not found

root@Kali:~# /etc/dfspace

-bash: /etc/dfspace: No such file or directory

Actually it should be present in etc directory but its nt there also

Comment: `dfspace` isn't a standard common or even a common one. Why did you expect to find it? Where did you encounter it? What does it do? Do you need that exact program or do you need a program with a similar functionality?

Comment: Yes I want to know another command doing the same thing as dfspace does.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like someone installed this script, `dfspace.sh`, which is available from GitHub: [misc-scripts / dfspace.sh](https://github.com/bmc/misc-scripts/blob/master/dfspace.sh). You can confirm if this is the case by doing the following command on one of these systems that has `dfspace` available.

```
 $ type dfspace
```

I would also check if these systems were SCO Linux. That OS included a command line tool `dfspace`.

- [dfspace -- report disk space](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/man/html.C/dfspace.C.html)

This command doesn't exist on any Linux variants I've ever come across, however you can use `df`, specifically with the `-h` switch to get "human" readable output.

#### Example

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root   50G   19G   28G  41% /
devtmpfs                           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              3.8G   14M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              3.8G  992K  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                              3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                              3.8G  1.7M  3.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                          477M   99M  349M  23% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home  402G  163G  218G  43% /home
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/` you've typed in front of `dfspace`.

At this place, this means that you want to execute a file called `dfspace` located under the root (`/`) directory

If you type :

```
$ dfspace
```

the shell will search for `dfspace` in all the directories mentioned in the `PATH` variable.

Comment: root@Kali:~# dfspace

-bash: dfspace: command not found

root@Kali:~# /etc/dfspace

-bash: /etc/dfspace: No such file or directory

Actually it should be present in etc directory but its nt there also

Comment: By the way I never seen commands and programs installed under `/etc`. How did you install this command ? If you just want to see the space left and occupied in your filesystems you can just type `df -h`.

Comment: I didn't install this command but It comes already installed there.It works on other Linux very well under /etc directory

Comment: On which distribution did you use it ? I don't find any clue for the existence of this command in Ubuntu. I have only evidence that this command exists in SCO Unix ([link](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/man/html.C/dfspace.C.html))

Comment: I am using Kali Linux and its debian derived os.